# javascript function gets called only with a different name

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a strange issue when I'm trying to call a method in javascript file. This .js file has the following two methods:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays)
{
  //set the expiry date as now + the specified number of days
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);

  //add the expiry date string to the cookie value
  var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; 
  expires="+exdate.toUTCString()+"; path=/");

  //set the cookie
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function setTheCookie(c_name, value, exdays)
{
  //set the expiry date as now + the specified number of days
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);

  //add the expiry date string to the cookie value
  var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; 
  expires="+exdate.toUTCString()+"; path=/");

  //set the cookie
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

On a button click when I use `onclick="setTheCookie('cookie_bar_hide', 'yes', 365)"` it gets called, but when I use `onclick="setCookie('cookie_bar_hide', 'yes', 365)"` it does not get called.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: What does `console.log(setCookie.toString());` return in the console?

Comment: What is the exact code for the whole element wherein you have this `onclick`?

Comment: Which browser are u testing in?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: The complete code can be seen on this [link](http://uat.knowledge.scot.nhs.uk/home.aspx). Right after the body tag I have cookies bar code.

Comment: It happens on all the browsers like firefox, chrome etc. I have tried debugging via firebug and the breakpoint does not get hit for setCookie function.

Comment: Are u sure it's not case sensitivity issue? I know you said `setTheCookie` works, but in your code it is called `SetTheCookie` with the capital `S`, maybe something similar is with `setCookie`?

Comment: see following line in function `setCookie()` there is error in this line that's why this function is not called. The line : `var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something else setting setCookie

From the console

```
> setCookie
function setCookie(name, value)
{
    document.cookie = escape($.trim(name)) + '=' + escape(value) + ';path=/';
}
```

Looking through all of the JavaScript files, `setCookie` is located in your `base.js` and `cookie.js`.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the issue. If the function with same name is present in two .js files, which function takes precedence and does it not depend on the number of parameters we pass in?

Comment: No, there is no overloading in JavaScript. The one that comes second overrides the previous one.

Answer (score -4):

I believe it may have to do with how you are calling your functions on the onClick event.  Call multiple methods like this:

```
  onClick="doSomething();doSomethingElse();"
```

Not with multiple OnClick's.

Let me know if this fixes the problem.